# Error "qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature" when installing Kali using qemu on Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, kali-linux, virtual-machine, cpu, qemu

First I installed qemu and kvm and then Created an image using...

```
sudo qemu-img create -f qcow2 debian.img 15G
```

...and when tried to load the iso file...

```
sudo kvm -hda debian.img kali-linux.iso -m 2048 -net nic -net user -soundhw all
```

then this error shows up...

```
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:EDX.syscall [bit 11]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:EDX.lm [bit 29]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
```

Comment: Try to add "-enable-kvm" and/or "-cpu host" maybe will solve your problem.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689775/how-to-fix-emulator-qemu-system-x86-64-warning-host-doesnt-support-requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the iso file is of 32-bit and without specifying it will take as a 64-bit image. So remove `kvm` and add `qemu-system-i386` before `-hda`. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

qemu-system-i386 -hda debian.img -cdrom kali-linux.iso -m 2048 -net nic -net user -soundhw all

Comment: You can improve this answer by adding what each flag does and how it collectively solves OP's question.